# Dividing Individual Spatial Polygons Equally in R

Tags: r, gis, spatial, polygons, r-sf

I have a shapefile of polygons that are the townships in the state of Iowa.I'd like to divide each element (ie each township) into 9 equal parts (i.e. a 3 x 3 grid for each township). I've figured out how to do this, but am having trouble forming a new dataframe out of the new polygons. My code is below. The data can be downloaded here: https://ufile.io/wi6tt

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
setwd("~/Desktop")

iowa<-st_read( dsn="Townships/iowa", layer="PLSS_Township_Boundaries", stringsAsFactors = F) # import data

## Make division 
r<-NULL
for (row in 1:nrow(iowa)) {
  r[[row]]<-st_make_grid(iowa[row,],n=c(3,3))
}

# Combine together
region<-NULL 
for (row in 1:nrow(iowa)) {
  region<-rbind(region,r[[row]])
}

region<-st_sfc(region,crs=4326) #convert to sfc
reg_id<-data.frame(reg_id=1:length(region)) #make ID for dataframe

# Make SF 
region_df<-st_sf(reg_id,region)
```

The last line gives the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, all_sfc_names[i], value = list(list( : replacement has 1644 rows, data has 14796
```

1664 is the number of rows in the initial Iowa dataframe. 
Clearly the number of rows does not match the number of elements.

This might be a general r thing, rather than a spatial one, but I figured I'd post the whole thing in case someone had an idea on how to do the entirety of this a little cleaner

Comment: I was not able to read in your zipped iowa shapefile you provided link for; however, using my own data and modifying your second loop to: `region[[row]] <-st_multipolygon(r[[row]])` the code worked for me and produced a result on final line